# Specifying a variable length formula in countifs

Tags: excel, vba, formula

How to give a variable length formula as input for countifs. Is there any possible way to do that?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(formula1,formula2...)
```

whereas formula1 has a range and a criteria.. because in my case the formula varies from one to many

Comment: Can you pls expand on what you mean by `because in my case the formula varies from one to many"`

Comment: I have to get conditions from user and with that conditions i have to apply to countifs. But here i cant count the no of conditions given by user. It may vary from one to many, so the formula in countifs varies from one to many.

Comment: May be some string substituion can be happened for eg

    For eg : str1= "range1,criteria1"

and substitute in countifs(str1). Whether this kind is possible?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to achieve - an example added to your question would help.

Comment: So, depending on "something" in the sheet, the Countifs() needs to evaluate one or more conditions. Is that correct? Can you please provide more detail as to what exactly that "something" in the scenario is that leads to the number of conditions in the CountIfs()? Try to put it into plain words. Without that logic, nobody will be able to help you. @brettdj is one of the best, so may want to provide the missing parts of the puzzle to help him give you a solution.

Comment: <waves at Ingeborg - flattery will get you everywhere!>

Comment: The user who uses this macro, will give input via a form. The input is the conditions. And my job is to count the no of occurences of the data which satisfies the conditions.But the problem is that i dont know the number of conditions the user can give. He can give any number of conditions. for eg condition1:*DSL* ,condition2 *<>IOP*,..... So as the number of conditions is not known i cant frame the countifs. So here's the problem i face

Comment: I could not evaluate the conditions seperately, as all conditions are pointed to same column. Eg:data as follows

PT-CHE-DSL-SLT, PT-CHE-DSL-PERF, PT-CHE-DSL-VECT, PT-CHE-DSL-REGRESSION-RUN1, PT-CHE-DSL-IOP and so on(repeatedly at random intervals). here i have to apply the above condition and have to count the number of it

Comment: The clarifications in these comments should be used to edit the question so it is more clear on first reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic range with a combination of OFFSET and COUNT
See this site as a reference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The OP is unclear as to what he means by "variable length formula" however my guess is that the range he is trying to perform the counts against is varying in length (given that he refers to the parameters of COUNTIFS as "formulas") . Using a dynamic range that would shrink and grow with OFFSET would achieve this.